# Does Hyper-V Replication support memory replication?

Tags: memory, replication, hyper-v-server-2012

Does Hyper-V replication support the replication of memory, or is it just the deltas between disk writes? ie, in a fail over situation would a server with a memory fault have this same memory fault replicated?

Comment: `1.` Everything I've ever read about it states that Hyper-V Replica replicates the VHD(X) of the VM, not it's state (memory). `2.` Replication does **not** occur in real time. `3.` There's no automatic failover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is just a live storage replication.  Replication occurs asynchronously, periodically. Automatic failover would be created via script.  See http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2012/10/05/automate-disaster-recovery-plan-with-windows-server-2012-hyper-v-replica-and-powershell-3-0.aspx as an example.  Typically replica is used for DR, and failover clustering at the application level for application fault tolerance.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Just wasn't sure if it provided some really deep level of live replication.